# Playframework scala class controller vs object controller

Tags: routes, playframework-2.3

How to define a controller class in playframework (that will be injected by a dependency container)?

For the `app/controllers/controller`

```
package controllers

import play.api.Play

/*object*class MainController(name:String) {
  import play.api.Play.current
  def index = Ok(Html("index ok "+name))
}
```

My `app/Global.scala`

```
package app
object Global extends GlobalSettings with SecuredSettings with Logger {
  override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]) = 
     new MainController("first")
}
```

My `conf/routes` file is

```
GET     /          controllers.MainController.index
```

I get the following error

```
[error] ............/conf/routes:1: value index is not a member of object controllers.MainController
[error] GET  / controllers.MainController.index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking up the official documentation. Which also contains links to repositories with examples of how to get started with the dependency injection framework of choice.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Might be worth keeping in mind that play 2.4.x will use Guice by default.

Comment: Thanks. It works with `GET     /          @controllers.MainController.index`